# Unable to repopulate a queue in python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

The code is getting exited when I run the following code

```
    import mysql.connector
    import mysql.connector.pooling as x
    import time
    from threading import Thread
    from queue import Queue

    dbconfig = {
      "database": "mydb",
      "user":     "root",
      "password": "rootpass",
      "host":"127.0.0.1"
    }

    cnxpool =x.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = "mypool",pool_size = 2,**dbconfig)
    q = Queue(maxsize=20)

    threads = []
    limit = 0
    fetch_size = 20
    flag = True

    def populate():
        cnx = cnxpool.get_connection()
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        global flag,fetch_size,limit
        while flag:
            cursor.execute("SELECT mycol from mytab limit " + str(limit)+","+ str(fetch_size))
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                print("Putting "+ str(row[0]))
                q.put(row[0])
            if cursor.rowcount < 20 :    
                for i in range(4):
                    q.put(None)
                flag = False
            limit = limit + 20
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()

    def consume():
        while True:
            item = q.get()
            if item is None:
                q.task_done()
                break
            time.sleep(1)
            print(item)
            q.task_done()

    for i in range(4):
        t = Thread(target=consume)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    y = Thread(target=populate)
    y.start()

    q.join()
    y.join()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    print("Completed")
```

Code is getting completed in jupyter notebook

But when I try to repopulate the queue even after removing the variable it hangs.

```
        import mysql.connector
        import mysql.connector.pooling as x
        import time
        from threading import Thread
        from queue import Queue

        dbconfig = {
          "database": "mydb",
          "user":     "root",
          "password": "rootpass",
          "host":"127.0.0.1"
        }

        cnxpool =x.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = "mypool",pool_size = 2,**dbconfig)
        q = Queue(maxsize=20)

        threads = []
        limit = 0
        fetch_size = 20
        flag = True

        def populate():
            cnx = cnxpool.get_connection()
            cursor = cnx.cursor()
            global flag,fetch_size,limit
            while flag:
                cursor.execute("SELECT mycol from mytab limit " + str(limit)+","+ str(fetch_size))
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    print("Putting "+ str(row[0]))
                    q.put(row[0])
                if cursor.rowcount < 20 :    
                    for i in range(4):
                        q.put(None)
                    flag = False
                limit = limit + 20
            cursor.close()
            cnx.close()

        def consume():
            while True:
                item = q.get()
                if item is None:
                    q.task_done()
                    break
                time.sleep(1)
                print(item)
                q.task_done()

        for i in range(4):
            t = Thread(target=consume)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)

        y = Thread(target=populate)
        y.start()

        q.join()
        y.join()

        for t in threads:
            t.join()

        print("Completed")

        del q

        q = Queue(maxsize=20)

        for i in range(4):
            t = Thread(target=consume)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)

        y = Thread(target=populate)
        y.start()

        q.join()
        y.join()

        for t in threads:
            t.join()




        print("Completed")
```

It hangs for ever.  Even creating a new queue doesn't help.  Where am I going wrong.  Kindly guide me.

Thanks in advance.

I am using Python 3.